# How to delete Kubernetes Finalisers Kubernetes.io/pv-protection?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-web-services, kubectl, eks

I am trying to delete the finalisers in the PV by issuing kubectl patch command and it deletes partially leaving behind Kubernetes.io/pv-protection

Described the PVC and able to see two entries

Finalisers: [Kubernetes.io/pv-protection external-attacher/ebs-csi-aws-com]

Command executed: kubectl patch pv pvname -p '{"metadata":{"finalisers":null}}'

It removes only external-attacher/ebs-csi-aws-com

Any idea how to remove the pv-protection finaliser?